# Phantom JS :first-child returning correct results half the time?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, phantomjs, screenshot, wolframalpha

I'm getting results from PhantomJS that are correct only half the time.

I'm trying to save the resulting planes overhead chart image on the page

http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=planes+overhead+90210

[The image I should be getting everytime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPKm7.jpg)

I've spent many hours getting to this point and now a few days stuck at this point. There doesn't seem to be a way to use queryselector for images so this was the best I could come up with. I thought it worked but the results work only half the time.

Many thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction with this.

While a screenshot cut down to the area of the page would work, the list of flights overhead often shrinks and expands - making it hard to set a static size that would encompass all results.

If there's a way in java script (or PhantomJS particularly) to select images instead of elements by Id or Class that would help a lot.

We are using this image to overlay over a live 360 camera at a remote observatory. We see a lot of planes pass the cameras while imaging and it would be nice to be able to know what is overhead at the current moment.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {
    width : 650,
    height : 480
};
page.open('http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=planes+overhead+90210', function (status) {

    just_wait();

    var clipRect = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelector('#answers:first-child').getBoundingClientRect();
    });

    page.clipRect = {
        top : clipRect.top,
        left : clipRect.left,
        width : clipRect.width,
        height : clipRect.height
    };

    function just_wait() {

        setTimeout(function () {

            page.render('flightsoverhead.png');

            phantom.exit();

        }, 3200);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're seeing because you're not waiting for the page to load, because some elements are loaded asynchronously. You can either wait a static amount of time like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 650, height: 480 };
page.open('http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=planes+overhead+90210', function (status) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){
            return document.querySelector('#Input').getBoundingClientRect();
        });
        var clipRectResult = page.evaluate(function(){
            return document.querySelector('#Result').getBoundingClientRect();
        });

        page.clipRect = {
            top:    clipRect.top,
            left:   clipRect.left,
            width:  clipRect.width,
            height: clipRect.height + clipRectResult.height
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(clipRect));
        page.render('flightsoverhead.png');

        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Or you can use [`waitFor()`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait for the elements to load

```
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};


var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 650, height: 480 };
page.open('http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=planes+overhead+90210', function (status) {
    var clipRect;
    waitFor(function _check() {
        clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){
            return {
                input: document.querySelector('#Input').getBoundingClientRect(),
                result: document.querySelector('#Result').getBoundingClientRect(),
            };
        });
        return clipRect && clipRect.input && clipRect.input.height > 50 && clipRect.result && clipRect.result.height > 50;
    }, function _onReady(){
        page.clipRect = {
            top:    clipRect.input.top,
            left:   clipRect.input.left,
            width:  clipRect.input.width,
            height: clipRect.input.height + clipRect.result.height 
        };
        page.render('flightsoverhead2.png');

        phantom.exit();
    }, 10000);

});
```

When you look at the markup:

```
<section id="answers">
    <section id="Input">...</section>
    <section id="Result">...</section>
    <section id="SkyMap:FlightData">...</section>
</section>
```

You're interested in `#Input` and `#Result`, so using `:first-child` will not be sufficient (by the way, `#answers:first-child` selects an `#answers` element that is itself a first child, you wanted to use `#answers > :first-child`). You can combine the dimensions of the two elements that you want with for a correct `clipRect`.

Comment: Artjom, 

Thank you so much for this! It works perfectly now. True genius!

Comment: It seemed this stopped working? I had a similiar problem and it was why I had chose #answers over Result or Input. 


  http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/scripts/wa.min.js?v=1.0.0&bt=1602081404:3
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('#Input').g
etBoundingClientRect')

  undefined:2
  :3
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('#Result').
getBoundingClientRect')

  undefined:2
  :3
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'clipRect.top')

  phantomjs://code/stack33.js:14

Comment: I should say I was using the static timeout function. This Error occurred after working for nearly 24 hours. I've been running phantomjs in a loop for 24 hours now, and tonight it finally gave me that error. I restarted the batch file running phantomjs and all is good now, its updating.  
Perhaps I will set a longer timeout and set the batch file that runs phantomjs, to exit after a few hours and have scheduler bring it back up so that error doesn't continue. Either way you've given me enough here to achieve what I need much better than what I had before. Thanks again!

Comment: I think it has something to do with how long it takes the page to load. I noticed the page is taking a long time now for me to load at this ip address. I'm wondering if my requests overloaded their server and it responded by slowing down my access.

Comment: It could be that Wolframalpha slowed you down, but you can increase the 10 second timeout of the second snippet to 30 or more seconds. `waitFor` guarantees that it will stop once the elements are there.